# How to show big add when I close 1 activity-Layout?

Tags: android, admob, addition

How can I set my application to show add over whole screen when I close 1 activity.
For Example My App has Menu Layout and Context layout, I want when I close Context layout and return to Menu layout, to show add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many "ad"-serving companies. But I prefer using Google's admob.

And that "BIG-FULLSCREEN ADs" are called **interstitials** here.

So, take a look at how to start [HERE](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced).

Once you understand it , then you can set anywhere in your (* but according to the guidelines.)